# Mock web service

Tags: java, web-services, testing, mocking, sockets

We have two components: enterprise application X, and Web service Y

We want to make our (automated) testing tool that will test application X (that interact with Y) only,
and we have not the web service Y available.

Notes:

- The testing tool will be a desktop application.
- We Don't want to use another external tools-e.g. SoapUI- for testing (as we want to automate the testing by running one application).

The question is: How we can mock the web service Y in our testing -desktop- application?
Does it is easy to mock it by Socket programming, or any other method/library?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution in Java 6

[web-services-without-ee-containers](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/03/jax-ws-web-services-without-ee-containers.html)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to let application X talk to Web service Y using an interface, such as IWebServiceY.

Coupled with **Dependency Injection**, this allows you to inject a mock of IWebServiceY into application X instead of the real, web service-based implementation of Web Service Y.

Comment: but currently we have no modification access to application X, we should test it only as it is.

Comment: I was going to write something but then I saw this.  I was going to write the same thing with different words, that is:

Create a base class objInteract

Create an inherited class from objInteract that actually pokes the web service.  Pass it in on the constructor whenever you'll need it.

Create a 2nd inherited class that returns canned data.  In test mode, pass in a pointer to that object on construction.