# Using Java to connect to SOAP UI Mock Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, search, interface, soapui

I have a mock web service running in soapUI 4.5.1 which looks up peoples names and addresses. I have a large dataset of names and addresses in a .txt file which I need to search for and verify with the web service.

The idea is to produce a count of the names which are valid and invalid.

I've created a Netbeans project to code a file reader to read in the text file and I need to connect to the web service to perform a bulk search.

Does anyone know a good tutorial to follow? Or suggestions of the best way to approach the problem? I've looked all over the internet, but I'm not too sure what I'm looking for..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement as far as I understand:

"Read a name and address from a text file and send them to a web service to verify"

1) If you DO NOT want to use a Java EE container then read this:
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/03/jax-ws-web-services-without-ee-containers.html .... as mentioned here [jax-ws-web-services-without-ee-containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235552/mock-web-service)

The only difference in your case will be that you will use SoapUI to interact with the endpoint.

2) If you want to use a Java EE container, which is available free with NetBeans if you have the free enterprise download of it.

The way I will do it; I will have a web service running on a server. I'll connect to the web service from SoapUI. I will send a username/address and the web service will return something for example a string "valid" or "invalid". So the mock code is on the server not in soapUI.

Since you are using NetBeans, you should create a web service using NetBeans;

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/intro-ws.html

Develop a SOAP based web service and connect to it with SoapUI. The web service is where your MOCK code will go, making it a MOCK Service which you can replace with real code afterwards.

You can put your file on the server or make it part of the application as a property file. In that case, create a web service on server that will verify the name/address list and send you back a count of valid and invalid.

**If the data is too huge and you want to keep it on a local file on your machine, then you need to use  [jax-ws clients appraoch](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html). You will read the data file in a class and then use the clients to send one at a time to the web service and keep a valid/invalid count.**
........................